# 3d QED with Chern-Simons term

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-theory, field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I would like to find the mass spectrum of a 2+1 QED theory with a Chern-Simons term such that the Lagrangian is of the form:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4g^2}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}A_\mu F_{\nu\rho}-A_\mu J^\mu
\end{equation}

Can someone say why this is a gauge invariant Lagrangian and if there is a mass gap in the spectrum. Any explicit calculation of the mass spectrum of these Lagrangian is very appreciated.

Comment: Without the source, the theory is quadratic, in $\bm A$, so if you choose a gauge, you can just read off the propagator. If it has a mass, then it should have a pole at nonzero momentum.

Comment: Here what I have thought thanks to your comment: I put for the moment $J_\mu=0$ and I have rewritten the Lagrangian in this way: $\mathcal{L}=A_\mu\left[\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\lambda}\partial^2+\lambda \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\lambda\right]A_\nu$. This is because the strength tensor is antisymmetric and Levi-Civita is antisymmetric, so I can rewrite the Chern-Simons term as twice $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}A_\mu \partial_\nu A_\rho$ (right?). But then the propagator is (in $\xi=0$) just that one in the parenthesis of the Lagrangian. Does that mean that this theory is not massive?

Comment: Ok, everything has to be corrected with the right factors, but I'm interested in the fact that I can write the Chern-Simons term in that way.

Comment: Related [98040](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98040/propagator-of-chern-simons-abelian-gauge-theory).